# Very strange SSIS error. DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I've got an odd one here.

I have a package that copies some data from one SQL server database to another, into staging tables. That data is then transformed and copied into live tables. This is all done via an SSIS package run by a SQL job.

It has been completely solid for months. This morning the job failed with the unhelpful "DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED" error in the SQL job, at the part where it copies the data into staging.

So I ran it manually from BIDS and it worked without any errors. Odd, I thought.
I then ran it manually from the server where it executes, but via the SSIS execution tool rather than the SQL job. No errors.

However, when I run it from the job, it fails. It always partially copies the data (1158 rows should be copied, so not a lot of data) but fails after 813 rows. I have looked at the data in row 814 and it all looks fine.

I am logged into the server with the same account that the SQL job runs under - it uses a credential mapped to a domain account.

So I temporarily put a restriction in to not import the row at 814, and now it works!! (it imports 1157 rows)

There are other tasks in the package that copy way more rows than this, and they are working fine.

So:
-Why does it work manually but not from the job?
-What is it about row 814 that's odd? I have copied the whole dataset into Excel, and there is nothing in that row that is odd, I am sure of it. And if there was something odd, why would it only affect the package when run from the job and not manually?

Finally, I put the row 814 back in, and took out another row at random, and it works!!

If I force an additional row in, it also works.

So it for some reason doesn't like the number of rows it's importing to be 1158! (but only when run via a SQL job)

I am completely stumped.

Comment: Which is more likely, that there's some abnormality in the data or that the 1158 rows always causes SSIS to fail?

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1158 * FROM sys.all_columns AS AC;` Even accounting for off by one, it's a simple thing to verify. Therefore, let's examine the facts, starting with your error. Based on my searching, it's usually a source driver issue but since you're going SQL Server to SQL Server, that seems less likely to be defective. Could you help us understand your scenario? What tasks are you using to transfer the data? What are your connection managers (ADO, OLE, ODBC, something else). Source and target DB version? Any other oddities we should know about (VPNs, cross domain, linked servers, etc)?

Comment: @user344996, is that the only error message available?  Are there additional errors you can share?

Comment: You need to give us more information. I guarantee your server isn't biased against the number 1158.

Comment: @billinkc Well, consider that it doesn't matter which row is removed, and it also works absolutely fine when a row is added, and that it also works fine when the package is run manually (either from BIDS or from the package execute util in Windows)

The failing task is a perfectly normal data flow task, SQL to SQL, OLE connections. Nothing else in the task at all.

Source SQL is 2005, destination is 2008

Any other info you need?

Comment: @AHiggins because it works when run from BIDS or Windows, I am unable to get any other error messages. Even though I have turned on logging on the package, it only states in the Windows Event Log that the package has failed, without any detailed error messages.

Comment: OK @theBenB, I'll take a shot in the dark based on a similar issue I once had: does the startup account for the SQL Agent Service have permissions on the SQL Agent Proxy account?  If there's a memory overflow and SSIS tries to write to a temp folder on the hard drive, both need to access the location [(see here)](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/933835).

Comment: @AHiggins Yes - the proxy credential that the SQL Agent account uses is the same account that I can successfully run the package under manually. If it was a memory overflow, surely adding a row wouldn't make it work? BTW, it has not failed since the problem occurred last week.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with an SSIS package and the problem ended up being a TRIGGER on one of the tables causing a problem during bulk insert. Took forever to narrow down because the violation was subject to the whims of bulk insert commits. The solution in my case was to change the SSIS data flow to not use bulk insert (turn off "fast load"). Made it way slower, but it works. Anyway, something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

What about RAM Memory used by this SSIS Process? I was struggling with similar issue on last weeks. I found that SSIS process is running out of RAM Memory on the server, due to big amount of RAM Memory used by SQL Server process. My SSIS process was failing when it was reaching 2GB of RAM Memory (available RAM at that moment), so **I just changed the Max RAM used by SQL Process in SQL Server Management Studio**, restarted the process, run the SSIS again, and it finished great. (Total RAM used by my SSIS package was about 2.7 GB). Hope this helps!
=)